# Python atexit.register not being called after termination

Tags: python, terminate, function-call, atexit

I am working on a program that needs to call a function right before exiting, and was successfully using atexit.register(myFunction) to do so, until it stopped working. Even when I try running just a simple script, the registered function is not being called...

Here is the simple code:

```
import atexit

def all_done():
    print ('all_done()')

print ('Registering')
atexit.register(all_done)
print ('Registered')
```

And the output is:

```
Registering
Registered
```

When it should be:

```
Registering
Registered
all_done()
```

What could be the problem? Like I said, it was working for a while, then suddenly stopped.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. I'm getting your expected output.

Comment: How do you run this code?

Comment: Like I said, it was working at one point. I get the sense that something must have messed up the module somehow, because I don't think anything is wrong with the code.

Comment: There isn't enough to go on, so a bit of a wild guess... the interpreter actually never terminates (i.e. you're using IDE that keeps the session alive)? The other options being, it gets terminated by a signal which is (can)not be handled and interpreter terminates without calling registered function?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using atexit, instead just

```
try:
   ...
finally:
   ...
```

which is now working. Still don't know why atexit doesn't work, though...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, 2 year old post.
In case you're having the same problem: keep in mind that, quote, "The functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called."

That means things like a system shutdown or `os._exit()` won't call the atexit function, but things like a keyboard interrupt or `sys.exit()` will do no problem.

example:

```py
import atexit

def all_done():
    print ('all_done()')

print ('Registering')
atexit.register(all_done)
print ('Registered')

os._exit()
```

will output

```
Registering
Registered
```

But, this code here:

```py
import atexit

def all_done():
    print ('all_done()')

print ('Registering')
atexit.register(all_done)
print ('Registered')

sys.exit()
```

will output

```
Registering
Registered
all_done()
```

Hope i was of help!

source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html